# How to retrieve ImageIcon elements from Vector Strings?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I am doing this small application for image viewing. The user enters the filename for eg. **image1.gif** and it will populate a `Vector` of `String` and from there, I am hoping to associate it with `ImageIcon` to display it on a `JLabel`. I'm stuck currently as I'm totally lost now as in how to continue from there. Can you guys give me some advise or suggestion? Thanks!

```
Vector <String> imageDetails = new Vector <String>;

ImageIcon imageGraphic = new ImageIcon(imageDetails.toString());

imageLabel.setText(imageDetails.get(0));
```

Comment: As `Vector` is a [legacy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24815413/230513), also consider another [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the Image from it's file name using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) library.

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("images/fileName.png"));
ImageIcon imageGraphic = new ImageIcon(image);
```

Call [JLabel#setIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) to set the icon of the label.

You can try any one based on image location.

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images/c.jpg"));

// Read from src/images folder
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/c.png"))

// Read from src/images folder
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/c.png"))
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825)

It's worth reading *Java Tutorial* on [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the element from the `Vector` that you want to load. For example...

```
ImageIcon imageGraphic = new ImageIcon(imageDetails.get(0));
```

As has already been stated, `ImageIO.read` would be a better choice than simply using `ImageIcon(String)` as `ImageIO` will throw an `Exception` should something go wrong with reading the image.

At about this point, I might also consider using a `Map` instead of a `Vector`, this will allow you to associate the `String` value with the actual image.  Take a look at the [Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your help and the link to find out more mate!