# Which one to use Vector or List (ArrayList) in creating custom layout for swing?

Tags: java, swing, vector, collections, layout-manager

I am working to create a custom layout for an application, as I am not able to implement the functionality using existing layouts like `CardLayout`.

I need to store various `Component` instances in a collection. As, I see in `CardLayout` source code, they've used `Vector` to hold `Card` instances.

By going through many answers on StackOverflow, I have learned, we should use `ArrayList` over `Vector`. But, which one should we prefer in the case of GUI related applications like holding `Component` instances in a `LayoutManager`.

Comment: Why do you think it makes any difference whether you create a GUI application or not? CardLayout uses Vector because it has been written when List didn't exist.

Comment: I thought that as all events in Swing are executed in EDT thread, so in a GUI application scenario, the collection does not need to be thread-safe to hold components. So, ArrayList would be better in that case!!

Comment: @JBNizet As it is today, we should go with List? :P

Comment: You said it yourself: *I have learned, we should use ArrayList over Vector*

Comment: Ok. There is an another little problem, I am having trouble with. I need to get the Key from a HashMap whose Value is known. As I know, there is no method for that or it is not considered as a good practice!

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question. But if that's what you need, you should probably have a Map<V, K> instead of a Map<K,V>. Or a BiMap. Don't forget that there might be several keys having the same value.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5654926/230513) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24815413/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for pointing out! I already seen your answer! And, for "implementing back/forward feature", what I need is full featured navigation with back/forward queue and breadcrumb support! And I am almost done with the layout! :D

Comment: Note how @camickr's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5657106/230513) uses a `List<JComponent>` internally.