# How exactly do I use the "fireContentsChanged" method in java.swing.AbstractListModel?

Tags: java, swing, listmodel

How exactly do I use the `fireContentsChanged()` method in [`java.swing.AbstractListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html)? This method is called when some of the `ListModel`'s elements have their "contents" changed.

1. Does this only mean that the index's object has changed somehow?
2. Or does it also include when the index's object has been replaced with a different object?
3. Can you use this for added/removed indexes? For example, let's say I remove 10 random elements from anywhere in the list. What `index0` and `index1` do I give? What if I insert 10 elements in random places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AbstractListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html) is an abstract implementation of `ListModel` that provides concrete implementations of the [`ListDataListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListDataListener.html) methods, but it contains no specific data structure internally. Receipt of a corresponding [`ListDataEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListDataEvent.html) allows the listening `JList` to update itself in response to a change in the `ListModel`.  [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) is a typical concrete subclass of `AbstractListModel` that manipulate a `Vector` internally. The [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.java) illustrates typical usage. In particular, `fireContentsChanged()` is "Sent when the contents of the list has changed in a way that's too complex to characterize with the previous methods," `fireIntervalAdded()` or `fireIntervalRemoved()`. Because `Vector` is a [legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24816033/230513) of the original `DefaultTableModel`, you'll want to use a more flexible alternative; `index0` and `index1` refer to elements of your chosen data structure.

> What if I insert 10 elements in random places?

Then `index0` and `index1` should ["bracket the change."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListDataListener.html#contentsChanged-javax.swing.event.ListDataEvent-)

> What does "bracket the change" mean?

In this context, *bracket* is used as a verb meaning to enclose or include; `index0` should include the lowest changed index, and `index1` should include the highest changed index. The range may include intervening cells, even though they were not changed. Happily, like `JTable`, `JList` renders only *visible* cells, so the marginal cost is bounded; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39169280/230513).

Comment: What does "bracket the change" mean?

Comment: I've elaborated above.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I think I get it now. So if the model had 20 elements, and I removed random ones, I would fire (0, 19). And if I added 5 elements randomly, I would fire (0, 24). Is that correct?

Comment: In the worst case, yes; your implementation is free to optimize such bulk updates, e.g. `DefaultListModel#clear()`.